# How to select default value that was created as create default and then was binded to user defined data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a table with all fields of user defined data types and NOT NULL. There are some defaults created as `CREATE DEFAULT` and binded to those user defined data types. It is given that way and I may not change it.
I need to insert data into this table from the source where there are some NULLS. How to use those defaults in my insert?

I've tried to get these defaults using defenition from `sys.default_constraints`, but there are no defaults created as `CREATE DEFAULT` in `sys.default_constraints`.

'''SQL

--Code I may not change

```
CREATE TYPE dt_myType FROM varchar(255) NOT NULL
GO
CREATE DEFAULT myDefault 
AS
''                     
GO
EXEC sp_bindefault 'myDefault', 'dt_myType'; 
GO
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    f1 dt_myType NOT NULL )
GO
```

--My code

```
insert into myTable
 (f1)
select 
 case f
   when 1 then 'example'
   else --I need default here
 end
from ...
'''
```

Comment: @SebastianBrosch it's not a duplicate, because in this case you cannot insert a default value (all columns are NOT NULL).

Comment: It is not a duplicate because defaults are not in table definition but are binded to user defined data types

Comment: That is largely irrelevant; `INSERT myTable(f1) VALUES (DEFAULT)` will work anyway, as will omitting the column. This works in exactly the same way as "proper" default constraints. The actual problem is crafting the `INSERT` query to do that when the non-default values are based on a query; there is (as far as I can tell) no way to access the actual value of the old-school default unless you fancy parsing definitions. You can't create a table variable or temp table with this type either. You may need to get ugly and write two queries, one for `f = 1` and one not (using `DEFAULT` for `f1`).

Comment: @SebastianBrosch . . . This is not a duplicate because the OP wants to insert multiple rows *from another table*, so `VALUES` is not appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Yes I see. I retracted the vote again. It is working on `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` but not on the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`. But this is also a problem without the custom default right?

Comment: I hoped I can select definition from sys.default_constraints where name = 'myDefault' But there is no myDefault there... Is there such default value stored somewhere in the system?

Comment: Yes -- you can find the definition in `sys.sql_modules` (`sp_helptext` will also retrieve it). The problem is that you would actually have to *parse* the value from there, which is impractical to say the least. If you only need the value to look it up once manually, it's good enough of course.

Comment: As far as I've got about 20 tables of about 50 fields each It's more difficult to write a lot of "if f = 1 ..." than to parse about 20 different defaults into my variables in the begining of my script

Comment: Jeroen Mostert, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have very many columns to test, you could do something like this:

```
insert into t (<other columns>, a, b)
    select <other columns>, x.a, x.b
    from x
    where x.a is not null and x.b is not null;

insert into t (<other columns>, a )
    select <other columns>, x.a
    from x
    where x.a is not null and x.b is null;

insert into t (<other columns>, b )
    select <other columns>, x.b
    from x
    where x.a is null and x.b is not null;

insert into t (<other columns>)
    select <other columns>
    from x
    where x.a is null and x.b is null;
```

This doesn't generalize well to many more columns.

Otherwise, here are some options I can think of:

- Loop through each record (say using a dreaded cursor) and construct the `insert` based on the presence of `NULL` values.
- Use an `instead of` trigger to basically construct the inserts, as described above.
- Insert the data so *all* values are default values and then update them with the values in the data.
- Figure out a way to parse the default value in the metadata, represent it as the appropriate type, and include it in your query.